# How to save the VS window layout for single/extended-multiple screen?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-on, multiple-monitors

I often work at the office using dual screen and at home using single screen. The window layout of Visual Studio 2010 is messing with me. I want to save/restore the layout so that I can quickly "switch" to the layout I want.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: see http://perspectives.codeplex.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Export your windows layout settings the way you like to use them at work into a .vssettings file
2. Export your windows layout settings the way you like ot use tham at home into a .vssettings file
3. Create shortcuts for devenv.exe /resetsettings [home.vssettings] and one for devenv.exe /resetsetting [work.vssettings]
4. That's it.  Just use one shortcut while at home to open VS and the other at work.  You can get more details here:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/05/the-resetsettings-switch-vstipenv0047.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to make this work when starting a solution directly?

Answer (score 11):

Best solution I've found is to use the [Layouts O Rama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c) extension. You can quickly switch between layouts using either keyboard shortcuts (that you can change) or the Layouts O Rama tool window:

[image: Screenshot]

---

Edit: Visual Studio 2015 includes this feature by default through the "Window" menu:

[image: Screenshot VS2015]

Comment: IMO it's the second most valuable extension after Resharper

Comment: OMG VS 2015 is awesome, thank you for adding the edit.

Answer (score 7):

The Perspectives extension seems to handle what you need.

> "Perspectives allows Visual Studio 2010 users to select and manage Visual Studio windows configurations."

http://perspectives.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a really neat extension. Also works for VS2012. I couldn't find it in the VS Gallery, but it can be downloaded from CodePlex.

Comment: Doesn't work on VS2013. See Layouts O Rama as suggested by @Otiel (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24532538/34022).

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to export the different layout settings into .vssettings files.  You can then import the setting of your choice and get back the desired layout.

To export the setting

- Tools -> Import / Export Settings
- Select "Export" and hit next
- Ensure "General Settings -> Window Layouts" is checked
- Complete the wizard and export the settings

I'm not 100% sure this will work for multi-monitor settings.  If it doesn't I would encourage you to file a bug on connect.

- http://connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2015, it includes a Save Window Layout and an Apply Window Layout menu item under Window.

> Visual Studio 2015 enables you to save up to 10 custom window layouts
>   and quickly switch between them. The following steps show how to
>   create, save, invoke, and manage custom layouts that take advantage of
>   multiple monitors with both docked and floating tool windows. First,
>   create a test solution that has two projects, each with a different
>   optimal layout.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In VS 17, Save window layout in Windows menu. Then apply window layout  with short cut. Ctrl + alt + 1 (2,3,4 etc).

[image]