# split VS2013 over two monitors permanently

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

So I'm working in VS2013 and I would very much like to split my workspace over 2 screens as follows:

- one screen on the left with the debug window and menus.
- one screen on the right with Test Explorer, Solution Explorer and my code.

Now I've managed to do this by dragging and dropping the code window and then doing the same with Test Explorer and Solution Exploerer.
The problem comes in when I close VS2013 and open it the next time I see it hasn't saved my setup and I have to repeat the process.
Is there anyway to save this configuration ,at a solution or permanent level?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939238/how-to-save-the-vs-window-layout-for-single-extended-multiple-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extension for it: [Layouts O Rama](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c). I use it myself and it works exactly as described. You can also store multiple layouts for different screen configurations.

Comment: That's amazing , Thank you!